# vertically aligning floated element

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation inside which I have two divs, one for the logo and the other for menu. Logo div was floated to left. So, it's parent's height is now the same as the logo div. But, the floated menu div sits at the top. I want to align it in the middle. How can I do the same? Please help me...

My code is given below...

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navigation clearfix">
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="navigation-menu">
            <a>HOME</a>
            <a>HOME</a>
            <a>HOME</a>
            <a>HOME</a>
            <a>HOME</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
}

.navigation {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.navigation-menu {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
}
```

And, here's the fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/ZghVk/

Answer (score 2):

Without defining a fixed height, you can change your layout to use `display:table` to facilitate easier vertical alignment.

Try changing your CSS to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/ZghVk/2/)

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.logo {
    display:table-cell;
}
.navigation-menu {
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.navigation-menu a{
    background-color:red;    
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `line-height`:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZghVk/1/)

```
.navigation-menu {
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    line-height:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do

```
.navigation-menu {
border:1px solid black;
background-color:red;
margin-left:40px;
}

.navigation-menu a{
margin-left:20px;
  }
```

you are trying to ".navigation-menu" you should use for "a" anchor tag[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
.navigation {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.logo {
    display:table-cell;
}
.navigation-menu {
    text-align:left;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.navigation-menu a{
    background-color:red;    
    float:right;
    padding:0 5px;
}
```

Hope it helps! :)